# Direct solution to maximum likelihood computation problem using the derivative of multivariate Gaussian w.r.t. covariance matrix

Tags: traces, matrix-inverse

For an application, I need to compute the maximum loglikelihood of data coming from a $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian random variable:
$$
\textbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \Sigma)
$$
where the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is a function two scalars $\sigma, \gamma$ such that $\Sigma = \sigma V + \gamma I$ and $V$ is symmetric and independent of both $\gamma$ and $\sigma$.

I have already computed the maximum likelihood using R `optim` function. However, I was wondering if I could directly compute the optimal $\sigma$ and $\sigma$ using some closed-form expression.

For this, I tried to follow the steps given in the answer provided by @greg for a  similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867022/derivation-of-derivative-of-multivariate-gaussian-w-r-t-covariance-matrix). However I am stuck at the step which involves expanding $\Sigma^{-1} = (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1}$.

My derivations are as follows. Using the same notations in the answer for $\Sigma=S$, $Z = X-\mu1$, $A : B = \text{tr}(A^TB)$,

\begin{align}
dL &= (S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^T S^{-1}) : dS \\
&= (S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^T S^{-1}) : (d\sigma V + \sigma dV + d\gamma I) 
\end{align}

Setting $dV=0$ and $d\gamma=0$ to get partial derivative w.r.t $\sigma$,
\begin{align}
dL &= (S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^T S^{-1}) : (d\sigma V) \\
& = d\sigma\, \text{tr}((S^{-1} - S^{-1}Z Z^T S^{-1})^TV) 
\end{align}

That implies,
\begin{align}
\frac{dL}{d\sigma} &=  \text{tr}((S^{-1} - S^{-1}Z Z^T S^{-1})^TV) \\
& = \text{tr}((\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} - (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} Z Z^T (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1})^T V)
\end{align}

Similarly, by setting $dV=0$ and $d\sigma=0$, we get partial derivative w.r.t $\gamma$,
\begin{align}
\frac{dL}{d\gamma} &=  \text{tr}(\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} - (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} Z Z^T (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1})
\end{align}

Is there a way to solve $\frac{dL}{d\sigma}=0$ and $\frac{dL}{d\gamma}=0$ to get closed-form solution for $\gamma$ and $\sigma$?